# Cout executing with incorrect variable values in for loop (while fails too?)

Tags: c++, for-loop, cout

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this, I'm trying to get an output to essentially "print code" for another project I'm working on to make a system so that the user can input the color of the text box, however whenever I try it always prints:

> if (*curent x value*==*current iteration of x loop*) and (*current y value*==*current iteration of y loop*

> cout<<system(Color 08)

(Without the space between, 256 times.) Everything here works fine, except for that in the system(Color ) part of the cout statement it's always 08, when c1 and c2 should change each time. Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time!

````
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c1, c2;
    for (int x=1; x<=16; x++)
    {
        if (x==1)
        int c1=1;
        else if (x==2)
        int c1=2;
        else if (x==3)
        int c1=3;
        else if (x==4)
        int c1=4;
        else if (x==5)
        int c1=5;
        else if (x==6)
        int c1=6;
        else if (x==7)
        int c1=7;
        else if (x==8)
        int c1=8;
        else if (x==9)
        int c1=9;
        else if (x==10)
        int c1=0;
        else if (x==11)
        char c1='A';
        else if (x==12)
        char c1='B';
        else if (x==13)
        char c1='C';
        else if (x==14)
        char c1='D';
        else if (x==15)
        char c1='E';
        else if (x==16)
        char c1='F';
        for (int y=1; y<=16; y++)
        {
            if (y==1)
            int c2=1;
            else if (y==2)
            int c2=2;
            else if (y==3)
            int c2=3;
            else if (y==4)
            int c2=4;
            else if (y==5)
            int c2=5;
            else if (y==6)
            int c2=6;
            else if (y==7)
            int c2=7;
            else if (y==8)
            int c2=8;
            else if (y==9)
            int c2=9;
            else if (y==10)
            int c2=0;
            else if (y==11)
            char c2='A';
            else if (y==12)
            char c2='B';
            else if (y==13)
            char c2='C';
            else if (y==14)
            char c2='D';
            else if (y==15)
            char c2='E';
            else if (y==16)
            char c2='F';
            cout<<flush<<"if (x=="<<x<<") and (y=="<<y<<")\nsystem(Color "<<c1<<c2<<")"<<endl;
        }
    }
    //cout<<c1<<" "<<c2;```

The now working code (Thanks François Andrieux!!!):

'''#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    for (int x=1; x<=16; x++)
    {
        if (x==1)
        c1='1';
        else if (x==2)
        c1='2';
        else if (x==3)
        c1='3';
        else if (x==4)
        c1='4';
        else if (x==5)
        c1='5';
        else if (x==6)
        c1='6';
        else if (x==7)
        c1='7';
        else if (x==8)
        c1='8';
        else if (x==9)
        c1='9';
        else if (x==10)
        c1='0';
        else if (x==11)
        c1='A';
        else if (x==12)
        c1='B';
        else if (x==13)
        c1='C';
        else if (x==14)
        c1='D';
        else if (x==15)
        c1='E';
        else if (x==16)
        c1='F';
        for (int y=1; y<=16; y++)
        {
            if (y==1)
            c2='1';
            else if (y==2)
            c2='2';
            else if (y==3)
            c2='3';
            else if (y==4)
            c2='4';
            else if (y==5)
            c2='5';
            else if (y==6)
            c2='6';
            else if (y==7)
            c2='7';
            else if (y==8)
            c2='8';
            else if (y==9)
            c2='9';
            else if (y==10)
            c2='0';
            else if (y==11)
            c2='A';
            else if (y==12)
            c2='B';
            else if (y==13)
            c2='C';
            else if (y==14)
            c2='D';
            else if (y==15)
            c2='E';
            else if (y==16)
            c2='F';
            cout<<flush<<"if (x=="<<x<<") and (y=="<<y<<")\nsystem(Color "<<c1<<c2<<")"<<endl;
        }
    }
    //cout<<c1<<" "<<c2;
}'''
````

Comment: `int c1=1;` and others are declaring a whole new `int` that has the same name as the one declared in `main`, initializes it, then immediately discards it. You would use `c1 = 1;` instead. Adding the type makes it a declaration.

Comment: When you fix the previously described bug, this still won't work as intended. `ch1` and `ch2` are `int` so when you print them it will display the numeric values of the characters you tried to assign (in the case of `A` to `F`). You need to make them `char` and assign character literals like `'1'` and `'2'` instead of integer literals like `1` and `2`.

Comment: Thank you so much, as soon as I set up c1 and c2 as chars, changed the numbers to 'number' and got rid of the ints and chars in front of when I assigned values to them it worked as intended.

Comment: Use a table instead of wearing out your copy-paste keys. `const char* digits="0123456789ABCDEF"; for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {char c1 = digits[x]; for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) { char c2 = digits[y]; ...`

Comment: Okay, will do, however will this work with the system(Color c1c2) statement I need it to? As I had problems with getting that to work, actually I guess i'll just try it. Thank you!